# How to determine the most recently viewed worksheet ("ActiveSheet") in EPPlus

Tags: excel, epplus, worksheet

When you open a workbook in Excel, it shows you the worksheet you were looking at when you last saved it.

How do you determine which sheet this is when you open a workbook using EPPlus?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ExcelWorksheet activeSheet = Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault(f => f.View.TabSelected);`

https://epplus.codeplex.com/discussions/456307

Comment: More than one sheet can be selected, so `Single()` can cause errors, and you can create a workbook with no worksheets selected using EPPlus if you don't set `View.TabSelected` for one of the worksheets, so `First()` can also cause errors.

Comment: Nice answer, @franzo. Feel free to mark your own answer as the correct solution to your question!